# How to add twig service to my bundle?

Tags: symfony, twig

I created new bundle (AcmeNotificationBundle) and I want to use it like a service like this:

```
$notification = $this->get( 'notification' );
$mess = $notification->getNotification( 'Some notification message' )->createView();
```

But in my bundle I need a twig service to render notification templates. I understand that I need something like this in Resources\config\services.yml file:

```
services:
twig:
    class: Path\To\Twig\Class
```

But I don't know what is the right path to twig class. Аnyone encountered this problem? What is the right way to add twig service to bundle?

Comment: I think this is a better answer for this: [10304468][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304468/injecting-twig-as-a-service-in-symfony2]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Templating service is already avaiable in your bundle. You can retrieve it from the container:

```
$container->get('templating');
```

You should be able to access twig service in a similar way:

```
$container->get('twig');
```

Rest of my answer uses templating service but you can easily replace it with twig if you really need to.

I think what you need is passing templating service to your notification service.

```
services:
    notification:
        class:     Acme\NotificationBundle\Notification
        arguments: [@templating]
```

Your Notification class would take the templating as a constructor parameter:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;

class Notification
{
    /**
     * @var Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine $templating
     */
    private $templating = null;

    /**
     * @param Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine $templating
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function __construct(TwigEngine $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }
}
```

Instead of `$notification->getNotification('Some notification message')->createView()` I'd probably do `$notification->createNotificationView('Some notification message')`. I'm assuming notification message is an entity and there's no need to pass templating to the entity.

Related documentation: [Referencing (Injecting) Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services)