# Get global application container of sf3 app inside a Translator extension service

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have a legacy symfony2 application which I'm trying to update to run on 3.4 LTS. In the app there is a service registered - a class extended from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator` and having just one method overridden. Inside this method we add translations from DB table specific to this very tenant (the app is multitenant one and based on subdomains) :

```
protected function loadCatalogue($locale)
{

    parent::loadCatalogue($locale);

    $twig = $this->container->get('twig');
    //then we fetch the tenant entity from Twig globals
```

This extension service is plugged in `services.xml` like:

```
    <service id="translator.default" class="Path\ToBundle\Translation\Class">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <argument type="service" id="translator.selector" />
        <argument type="string" >%locale%</argument>
        <argument type="collection" />
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="cache_dir">%kernel.cache_dir%/translations</argument>
            <argument key="debug">%kernel.debug%</argument>
        </argument>
    </service>
```

Now the problem is that by running this code the framework tells me this service container is only aware of translator-specific components like "translation.loader.csv", "translation.loader.dat" and so on. Which is correct from DI point of view and hiding the other unnecessary ones for this component. But I need to somehow get the twig component from the application-wide container.

PS. Just as a reminder, the base `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator` constructor looks like:

```
 * @param ContainerInterface        $container     A ContainerInterface instance
 * @param MessageFormatterInterface $formatter     The message formatter
 * @param string                    $defaultLocale
 * @param array                     $loaderIds     An array of loader Ids
 * @param array                     $options       An array of options
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $formatter, $defaultLocale = null, array $loaderIds = array(), array $options = array())
{
```

**UPDATE:** 
Using the hint from the 1st answer, I injected the `$twig` parameter into the constructor of my service:

here is the service in services.xml:

```
class MyTranslator extends Translator {

    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, ContainerInterface $container, MessageFormatterInterface $formatter, $defaultLocale = null, array $loaderIds = array(), array $options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($container, $formatter, $defaultLocale, $loaderIds, $options);

        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
```

Here is how `services.xml` looks now:

```
    <service id="translator.default" class="MyBundle\MyTranslator">
        <argument type="service" id="twig" />
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        <argument type="service" id="translator.selector" />
        <argument type="string" >%locale%</argument>
        <argument type="collection" />
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="cache_dir">%kernel.cache_dir%/translations</argument>
            <argument key="debug">%kernel.debug%</argument>
        </argument>
    </service>
```

and here is the error I'm still getting after the changes (no cache - testing in dev env) :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\MyTranslator::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator given, called in /path/app/cache/dev/ContainerXk9jorc/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3883 and defined in /path/MyBundle/Translation/MyTranslator.php on line 22
```

Cache cleared and the cache folder is removed:

```
root@3e5838c2cff6:/var/www/project# rm -rf app/cache/
root@3e5838c2cff6:/var/www/project# php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
[27-Apr-2018 16:59:30 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Translation\MyTranslator::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator given, called in /var/www/project/app/cache/dev/ContainerKj0tifc/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3886 and defined in /var/www/project/src/Project/MyBundle/Translation/MyTranslator.php:22
```

Comment: Is the definition of the service overloaded in another xml?

Comment: hm, no, I don't think so. If you mean the MyTranslator service, shouldn't be overridden neither in any other xml nor in yml

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Translator:

```
private $twig;

public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, ContainerInterface $container, $formatter, $defaultLocale = null, array $loaderIds = array(), array $options = array())
{
   $this->twig = $twig;
   parent::__construct($container, $defaultLocale, $loaderIds, $options);
}
```

Now you can access twig with $this->twig eevrywhere inside of your translator.

Comment: looks like it expects an instance of `ServiceLocator` as the 1st param to the constructor. At least I'm getting this error when trying to override the contstructor in my class and add an instance of `TwigEnvironment` as the 1st param

Comment: Do you use dependency injection in your app? https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Comment: you mean autowiring feature? Haven't changed the config yet to turn it on, but I assume you may be right, let me try that. Update: added autoeiring, autoconfigure , but still getting the same error. But thanks for the hint, will look further

Comment: Can you paste the full error you're getting with the ServiceLocator? Also did you updated `services.xml` and added twig as the first argument to the service `translator.default`?

Comment: done in the question, see update section. Thanks to you both!

Comment: @Alexey looks like you can only use twig if you use autowiring too. I think you need to use the EngineInterface (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937387/8411841)) and use 'templating' inside the service.xml

Comment: the thing is that I need @internal `::getGlobals()` method, not render (from the engine). That's bad, I know , but wanted to avoid rewriting this as we're storing the tenant entity in twig globals

Comment: It appears that your `services.xml` file is not updated in the cache and the container tries to instantiate MyTranslator class passing the container as the first arg. Can you try please to clear the cache: `php bin/console ca:cl --env=dev` then if it's still not working with `rm -rf var/cache/*` or `rm -rf app/cache`

Comment: @tudor just added two lines to the question. Removed the cache and then see the error when trying to launch the CLI command